# Перенос разряда в 16-чной системе счисления

Tags: lisp

Здравствуйте) Задача такая  - сложить 2 числа, представленных в 16-чной системе счисления.
Я буквенные коды перевожу в цифры и складываю. 
Например ( A 3 ) + ( F 4) = (25 7)
Сейчас задача такая, что надо прочитать список слева направо (число записано в обратном порядке просто) и проверить , нужен ли перенос разряда из младшего в старший, то есть
( 25 7 ) перевести ( (25-15) (7+1)) = (10 8)
Есть такой код пока... Но не работает почему-то..

```
(defun Perenos ( l )
  (cond ((eq (cdr l) nil) l) 
        ((< (car l) 15)
         (cons (- (car l) 15) (F (car l) l))) 
        (T (cons (car l) (Perenos (cdr l))))))

(defun F (h l)
  (setq b (- h 15))
  (rplacd l (cons (+ 1 (cadr l)) (cdr (cdr l)))) 
  (rplaca l b)
  (Perenos (cdr l)))
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста)

Comment: сделайте отступы как принято, сложно читать. Здесь: http://lisper.ru/pcl/syntax-and-semantics есть описание форматирования Lisp кода, придерживайтесь пожалуйста.

Comment: Вообще, это неуважение к читающему.

Comment: постаралась исправить, надеюсь, сейчас читать вам не так сложно.

Comment: пофиксил как надо

Comment: Не работает потому, что ошибки в коде. Как минимум, сравнение в `cons` не в ту сторону. Сейчас вызов `(Perenos '(25 7))` так и вернет `(25 7)`, потому что пойдет по последней ветке и `(car '(25 7))` так и останется. Если поменять условие на `(> (car l) 15)`, то вернет внешне правильное `(10 8)`. Дальше я логику не проверял, могут быть где-то еще проблемы.

Алсо, `F` — малополезная куча индийского кода, вместо которой достаточно правильного `cons`. См. ответ @Vladimir Gordeev.

Answer (score 1):

Легче самому написать. Писал на Scheme, потом перевёл на CL, так что может тут где есть ошибка.

```
(defun simplify-nums (l)
  (cond ((null l) NIL)
        ((null (cdr l)) l)
        ((> (car l) 15)
         (cons (- (car l) 15)
               (simplify-nums (cons (+ 1 (cadr l)) (cddr l)))))
        (T (cons (car l) (simplify-nums (cddr l))))))
```

Comment: Да, есть что-то чарующее в этих головоломках...

Comment: Извините, но минусанул, потому что нет даже никаких комментариев. Сунуть кусок кода «делайте вот так» — заведомо мало чем поможет делу.